Application-Insight does not show page views either with Automatic Instrumentation or SDK instrumentation
I'm deploying a web app in Azure, on a linux machine, using python, deploying as code. Per docs, I should be able to enable automatic instrumentation of Application Insights
I have enabled the collection on the app itself, and I confirmed that it's pointing to the correct resource group:

But I see nothing in the Application Insights dasbhoard.
In the application insights Logs I can see the odd trace and dependency exception. But I cannot see page views or visitors or the host of other metrics that should be automatically tracked.
I tried to then implement tracking with code, using the SDK, but again, to no avail:
if (
not hasattr(trace.get_tracer_provider(), "_is_sdk_configured")
or not trace.get_tracer_provider()._is_sdk_configured
):
     trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())

    otlp_exporter = OTLPSpanExporter(
    endpoint="https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com",  
 # Correct Ingestion Endpoint
    headers={
        "x-ms-monitor-ingestion-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },  # Using the instrumentation key as the ingestion key
)
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(BatchSpanProcessor(otlp_exporter))


I SSHd into my site on Azure using CLI and I could manually run a script that printed a message to a trace logger, so I know the configurations are accurate. But I cannot understand why, under both automatic and manual implementation I cannot see page views or users.
Thank you

please provide the code in text format rather than Image.

Configure automatic instrumentation for the Python application. This typically involves installing the Application Insights SDK for Python and setting the instrumentation key in the application's configuration.
The code which you provided attempts to manually configure OpenTelemetry instrumentation for sending traces to Application Insights using an OTLP exporter.

Here is a simple Python code snippet for setting up automatic instrumentation using the Application Insights SDK for Python.

from flask import Flask
from applicationinsights import TelemetryClient

app = Flask(__name__)

# Initialize Application Insights telemetry client with your instrumentation key
app_insights = TelemetryClient("YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Track a custom event
    app_insights.track_event("PageView", {"url": request.url})
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()


We import Flask for creating a web application and TelemetryClient from applicationinsights for sending telemetry data to Application Insights. We create a Flask app instance. We initialize the TelemetryClient with your Application Insights instrumentation key.

Define a route for the homepage ("/") and track a custom event ("PageView") with the current URL when the route is accessed. Finally, start the Flask app with app.run().


Result:

Reference:

Azure Application Insights SDK for Python

